# Spring kotlin - How to inject internal class to public class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, design-patterns, architecture

I have some problem but also I don't know if my approach is right so I decided to ask you about it. I try to create public facade (for REST controllers or another modules) in application layer which should communicate with domain layer. The problem is that it seems to me that everything in domain should be internal and when I want to inject some service from domain to facade then intellij returns me error: **'public' function exposes its 'internal' parameter type SomeService**. What is the best approach for this case? Should I make interface SomeService as public? But then any other modules also could inject it what is probably wrong :/

example code:

```
applicaion layer: 

class MyFacade(
    private val myInternalService: InternalService
){
   fun save(...){
       return myInternalService.save(...)
   }
}

domain layer:

internal interface InternalService {
    fun save(...)
}

and rest implementation of domain...
```

Comment: Actually, it makes a lot of sense. If initializing a `MyFacade` requires using some internal objects then it means initialization itself should be also considered an internal thing. You can leave your `MyFacade` public, but its constructor should be internal like this: `class MyFacade internal constructor(...)`. I don't know Spring DI, so I don't put this as an answer, but I guess it can use private constructors as normal. If not, you can try a private property.

Comment: Wow, I haven't known that in kotlin is something like internal constructor but it looks that it works so thanks a lot for advice :D

Comment: @broot you should write it as answer